# What is the best way to store local settings in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I want to store some settings in swift app.

I tryed to use NSuserdefaults, but when app relaunched settings is empty.

In my root controller i want do this:

```
if(Storage.isset("key")){
    // do 1
}else{
    // do 2
}
```

Storage - class for working with user defaults
When i close app on device and launch again - user defaults is empty.

I need another solution to do this.

I am using Swift with Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)
Testing app on my device.

Please Help, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
var setting = "Some Setting"
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

// Save Settings
userDefaults.setObject(setting, forKey: "key")

// Load Settings
if let userSettings = userDefaults.objectForKey("key") {
     print(userSettings) // prints "Some Setting"
}
```